# DOM Exception 11 on XHR request occurring only in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, xmlhttprequest

I have a very simple function that downloads chunks of a file using an xhr request that looks like so:

```
var blobXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

//api.media.chunkURL() returns the correct URL for each chunk
blobXHR.open("GET", api.media.chunkURL({
            fileId: fileID,
            chunkId: chunkNumber
            }));

blobXHR.responseType = "arraybuffer";

blobXHR.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log("Error: ", e);
            };

var arrayBuffer;
blobXHR.onload = function (e) {
            arrayBuffer = blobXHR.response;
            };

blobXHR.send();
```

Now this download function works without any hitches at all using Chrome, Firefox, and just about every Android browser.  Unfortunately, when using anything Safari or iOS based I get a very vague error in blobXHR.onerror().  When I output this error to the console I get this response under "e.currentTarget.responseText":

```
Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11
```

I've looked up many questions similar to this and nothing has seemed to work.  Any reason why I would be experiencing this with only Safari/iOS browsers?

Edit: This is what I get when I console.log(blobXHR) within onerror():

[image: BlobXHR state on onerror()]

Comment: If you output the XMLHttpRequest state (console.log) what does it show?

Comment: Added a console.log(blobXHR); inside onerror() and just posted the image of the result.  Hope that was what you were asking for.

Comment: What about changing your onload to this: `blobXHR.onload = function (e) {
            console.log( "State: " + blobXHR.readyState + ", Status: " + blobXHR.status ); arrayBuffer = blobXHR.response;
            };` What does that print?

Comment: It comes back with 4 inside onload() and just about everywhere else I put it.

Comment: can you make it past the line that grabs the response? What does the response show as?

Comment: Just realized that it doesn't ever make it into blobXHR.onload(), that 4 being returned previously on the readyState from before only occurred because my file had expired.  When the file I'm trying to download is still available, it goes straight into onerror() and doesn't output anything within onload() including the response.  Sorry if I confused you from before.

Comment: is this connecting to a server locally? http or https? and is the page the same protocol as what is requesting? (i.e. both https) both in the same subdomain?

Comment: Currently I am using a local server to test but I just tested and got the same output using https.  Also, I outputted blobXHR.readyState to the console immediately after my blobXHR.open() call and received a -1.

Comment: Can you please print the exact URL your function is sending to `open`?

Comment: Yup, here it is locally:
  
    http://localhost:5000/v3/file/6f9fe6a7-7395-479e-8ab2-4c0b8cf4b0c7/chunk/0/

Comment: Can you also add this function: `blobXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {  console.log( "State: " + blobXHR.readyState + ", Status: " + blobXHR.status + ", Text: " + blobXHR.statusText  );}`

Comment: Alright I added it right after my open() call and got: "State: 4, Status: 0"  I'll do it now with statusText as well. 1 sec.  And thanks so much for helping!

Comment: I'm wondering if it's seeing this a CORS and webkit in Safari doesn't allow localhost for that?

Comment: Do you have access to your router? Can you add a hostname like "myfakesite.com" for the server's IP address and port? And then use that instead of localhost to see if that fixes it?

Comment: For some reason the blobXHR.statusText seems to be coming up as blank

Comment: Do you have access to your router? Can you add a hostname like "myfakesite.com" for the server's IP address and port? And then use that instead of localhost to see if that fixes it?

Comment: We do have a dev server and live website right now that I have tested on and I get the same response.  A coworker has just told me that it might have something to do with us hosting our files on an amazon s3 web server however.

Comment: Question, is your web page served from localhost:5000? If so, can you try changing your `GET` URL to this: `/v3/file/6f9fe6a7-7395-479e-8ab2-4c0b8cf4b0c7/chunk/0/`? So remove the http, host and port

Comment: Seems to unfortunately give me the same result :( After doing a bit more snooping I've realized that my server gives back a 302 after making my open() call which is correct and what I want.  But I just found this question that seems to be very similar to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332919/safari-fails-cors-request-after-302-redirect my coworker says that the only difference between our application is that we don't use credentials like this user does.

Comment: Wait, are you doing a CORS (which is what that problem is referring to)? The web page is on a diff. URL/domain than the requested url? If so, then it changes everything. Are you sure it's CORS?

Comment: Alright so after discussion with my senior coworker he says that my original request is not CORS, my 302 response is also not CORS, but the URL that the server goes to to grab the file/chunks IS in fact CORS.

Comment: Also it appears that Safari doesn't receive the 302 from our server even though in the server logs it says that it is sending the browser that.

Comment: Just wanted to say that because of your help we were able to identify this problem that was plaguing us for weeks and eventually solve it!  It was completely due to CORS and only took some minor changes once I brought it up to one of the backend guys.  Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem. Mind if I add that as the answer?

Comment: No problem, go for it!

Comment: Glad you finally got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a CORS issue. Make sure your server is properly configured to allow this:

http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Also be mindful that Safari won't allow localhost for CORS.