# Cross-origin redirection denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy in Safari

Tags: safari, cors

We have an api endpoint that redirects to another server. It's called via XHR and seems to work fine in most browsers, except for Safari (specifically on iOS).

The error I'm getting in the console is:
Cross-origin redirection denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

We have CORS on the page that does the redirection and on the other server. The redirection page sets:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
```

The other server has:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

How can I allow redirection in the CORS policy?

Comment: If the cross-origin XHR works in other browsers but not in Safari, it sounds like a bug in Safari that’s making it non-conforming to the current CORS requirements specified in https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/. So please consider filing a bug at https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: It probably is a bug with Safari, but I was hoping there was a workaround.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, but nothing mentioned there seems to work.

Comment: Please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824661/cors-request-not-working-in-safari . Hope it helps. I faced the same issue with an ASP .net website. We were unable to resolve it at that time.

Answer (score 11):

The W3C specification and other authoritative sources directly forbid wildcard `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` when used with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

> Note: The string "*" cannot be used for a resource that supports credentials.

https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-requests

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials

> If credentials mode is "include", then `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cannot be `*`.

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials

## Further steps

Because your question lacks details, let's make some definitions:

- *domain-a* is the domain of your client code
- *domain-b* is the domain of the endpoint where your make request to
- *domain-c* is the domain where the request is finally redirected to

First of all, I think, you want to make a workaround. As long as you told all endpoint are under your control, so you either:

- Make direct request from *domain-a* to *domain-c* (or even make a conditional request, if redirect depends on parameter)
- Expose another endpoint in your backend that wraps request to *domain-b*

It is also important to report a bug to [WebKit tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/) if it really violates the spec. To easier reproduce the case I made a CherryPy app, which you could attach to the report. The step to run it:

1. Add "127.0.0.1   domain-a domain-b domain-c" to your `/etc/hosts`
2. Put the following code into `corsredirect.py`
3. Run these commands in terminal

   ```
    virtualenv -p python3 venv
    . venv/bin/activate
    pip install cherrypy
    python corsredirect.py
   ```
4. Point your browser to http://domain-a:8080 and push the button

There's the app.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
'''
Add localhost aliases in /etc/hosts for "domain-a", "domain-b", "domain-c".

The flow is: [domain-a] --CORS-GET--> [domain-b] --redirect--> [domain-c].
Open as http://domain-a:8080/
'''


import cherrypy


def cors():
  cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'

cherrypy.tools.cors = cherrypy._cptools.HandlerTool(cors)


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
      <title>CORS redirect test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <button>make request</button>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
          document.querySelector('button').onclick = function()
          {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', 'http://domain-b:8080/redirect', true);
            xhr.onload = function()
            {
              var text = xhr.responseText;
              console.log('success', text);
            };
            xhr.onerror = function()
            {
              console.error('failure');
            };
            xhr.send();
          };
        </script>
      </body>
      </html>
    '''

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.config(**{'tools.cors.on': True})
  def redirect(self):
    raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('http://domain-c:8080/endpoint')

  @cherrypy.expose
  @cherrypy.config(**{'tools.cors.on': True})
  @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
  def endpoint(self):
    return {'answer': 42}


if __name__ == '__main__':
  config = {
    'global' : {
      'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
      'server.socket_port' : 8080,
      'server.thread_pool' : 8
    }
  }
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: I have also tried it with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false` but it doesn't fix this problem. On my production code I have this set to false already.

Comment: @Noodles To make it clear that the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentialsy value is not the problem, tou might want to consider updating the example code in the question to use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false` and not use `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. Because as-is it’s a bug.

Comment: @Noodles I've updated my answer. Can you verify that Safari fails the request in the app?

Answer (score 3):

Enabling HTTPS on both servers has solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem hosting my API on a Heroku app. On Chrome and Firefox, requests to my API from another domain were working perfectly, but on Safari, I was getting a frustrating "Cross-origin redirection denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy".

After some researching, it seems there might be a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32332919/safari-fails-cors-request-after-302-redirect) in Safari that prevents some redirects with CORS. I was able to get around this by requesting the Heroku app directly (`myapp.herokuapp.com/api`) instead of to my domain (`mydomain.com/api`).

If you've got a setup where there are redirects to your API, requesting the root domain directly might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change your url, you can get a try with a proxy pass configuration on your Apache. The call will look like to be on the same domain but it will not.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

For more check :  http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 1):

For just about anything other than a "Simple request", the authoritative sources deny wildcard for the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header and require you to explicitly set the header "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".

Here is what [Mozilla states for "Simple request"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests):

> The only allowed methods are:
>
> - GET
> - HEAD
> - POST
>
> Apart from the headers set automatically by the user agent (e.g.
>   Connection, User-Agent, etc.), the only headers which are allowed to
>   be manually set are:
>
> - Accept
> - Accept-Language
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
>
> The only allowed values for the Content-Type header are:
>
> - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> - multipart/form-data
> - text/plain

When your request doesn't meet the "Simple Request" requirements you probably fall into ["Preflighted Requests"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).

> methods other than GET, HEAD or POST. Also, if POST is used to send request data with a Content-Type other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain, e.g. if the POST request sends an XML payload to the server using application/xml or text/xml, then the request is preflighted.

As for credentialed requests -

> Important note: when responding to a credentialed request,  server must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding. Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Since you didn't provide the actual HTTP requests and responses from your page and servers I will have to make some assumptions. I am assuming that your page is loaded under the domain foo.example and that your API is under the same foo.example domain and that your "other" server is on the domain bar.example.

You likely need to setup your page to make a redirect request to the "other" server with these Headers:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, CUSTOM-HEADER
```

You then likely need to setup your "other" server to respond to an Options request with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-requested-with, Content-Type, CUSTOM-HEADER
```

Then your page should be able to finish the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" header.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the problem